# How to change font size of all paragraphs in div with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I'm trying to change the font size and line height of all paragraphs in my div depending on the size of the screen--for mobile responsiveness. As you can see in the example, when I attempt to change the paragraph sizes with JS, it only alters the first element. When I do it in CSS it works, just not JS.

```js
const textContP = document.querySelector('.textcont p');
textContP.setAttribute("style", "line-height: 5vw");
textContP.style.fontSize = "3vw";
```

```css
.textcont p {
      font-size: 4vw;
      line-height: 5vw
  }
```

```html
<div class="textcont">
  <p>test</p>
  <p>test2</p>
</div>
```

Comment: `depending on the size of the screen--for mobile responsiveness` in this case you ***really*** should be using [CSS Media Queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries), not JS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the `document.querySelector()`. It selects just the first element found. You need to use `document.querySelectorAll()` to get all `<p>` tags.

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.textcont p').forEach(p => {
  p.style.lineHeight = "5vw";
  p.style.fontSize = "3vw";
})
```

```css
.textcont p {
      font-size: 4vw;
      line-height: 5vw
  }
```

```html
<div class="textcont">
  <p>test</p>
  <p>test2</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`querySelector` selects only the first element.
so use `querySelectorAll` this will put all selected elements in an array, then you can loop through the array using `for loop` or `for each` to change all the elements.

NOTE: make sure you give all elements the same class for that. and make sure to add the dot `.` when you add classes in selectors

```
const textContP = document.querySelectorAll('.textcont p');
textContP.forEach(item => {
    item.style.lineHeight = "5vw";
    item.style.fontSize = "3vw";
  });
```

learn more about loops [here](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_for.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Note: I've used a time out in both these examples to show them working.

#### Solution one

Use [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) to grab all the paragraphs and use [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) to iterate over the returned node list updating the style for each paragraph.

```js
setTimeout(() => {
  
  const paras = document.querySelectorAll('.textcont p');

  paras.forEach(p => {
    p.style.lineHeight = '4vw';
    p.style.fontSize = '3vw';
  });

}, 2000);
```

```css
.textcont p {
  line-height: 5vw;
  font-size: 4vw;
}
```

```html
<div class="textcont">
  <p>test</p>
  <p>test2</p>
</div>
```

#### Solution two

Adjust [the underlying stylesheet](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleDeclaration/setProperty) using [CSS variables](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties) instead.

```js
setTimeout(() => {
  
  const { style } = document.documentElement;
  
  style.setProperty('--lineHeight', '4vw');
  style.setProperty('--fontSize', '3vw');

}, 2000);
```

```css
:root {
  --lineHeight: 5vw;
  --fontSize: 4vw;
}

.textcont p {
  line-height: var(--lineHeight);
  font-size: var(--fontSize);
}
```

```html
<div class="textcont">
  <p>test</p>
  <p>test2</p>
</div>
```